# Python error : No module found, even after adding directory to PATH

Tags: python, pip, path, environment-variables, yfinance

I installed `yfinance` in Anaconda Prompt (on Windows 10): `pip install yfinance --user`.

I got the message :

> WARNING: The script sample.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\joseph\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
> Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.

I added the path `C:\Users\joseph\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\Scripts` to `Path` in `System variables`.

But I'm still getting an error message when importing `yfinance` in Python (Spyder 3.7):

`ìmport yfinance`

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'yfinance'

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling yfinance after adding sample.exe to the PATH, assuming that failed on install?

Comment: Do you mean I should uninstall it and reinstall it ?

Comment: If you have successfully edited your PATH, (excellent answer below from Aditya Sarin), what happens when you run, pip install yfinance --user

Comment: I get a lot of : Requirement already satisfied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `python.exe` path along with the `scripts` path in your system variables.

Click on ‘New…‘ to add the ‘Path’ variable (note that if your ‘Path’ variable already exists, then click on ‘Edit…’ instead)

[image]

Before you type any values, you’ll need to locate the relevant Python paths. The paths that you’ll need to get are:

1. The Python application path, which is the folder where you originally installed Python;
2. The Python Scripts path. The Scripts folder should be located within the Python application path.

For the Variable name, type ‘Path‘.

For the Variable value, copy the full Python application path, then use semicolon (as highlighted in yellow below), and finally copy the Python Scripts path.

This is how my Variable value looks like:

```
C:\Users\Ron\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32;

C:\Users\Ron\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts
```

Put all the values together in the New User Variable box

Press ‘OK’ and you would then see your new Python Path under the ‘User variables’ section.

Comment: Thx. I added to the Path both : `C:\Users\joseph\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37` (There are 2 files there : site-packages and Scripts) and also `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3` where Python is. But it still doesn't work

Comment: Add  `C:\Users\joseph\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37` as well as `..\scripts` separately.